# Restrict Access to internet for all MAC except listed on LINKSYS Wireless-N ADSL2+ Modem Router

Tags: router

I create Access Restriction List on LINKSYS Wireless-N ADSL2+ Modem Router.

I added 2 Mac addresses to list and those 2 PC's have internet. Now I connect my 3rd PC to this router and it also has connection to internet (I don't want it, it's not on the list).

How can I block all access to router except mac's I add to list?

Wireless access restriction works the way I want.

Here is link to manual where I can see only 1 page dedicated to that problem:

http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/1224639048333/WAG160N_V10_UG_NC-Web.pdf

page 16, Access Restrictions > Internet Access Policy

Do I need create two lists or something? First: DENY ALL (how?), Second: ALLOW LISTED

Picture of Access Restriction Tab:

[image]

List of Computers:

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of this page's settings/

Comment: adresyMAC1 contain 2 mac addresses, I posted clean policy list picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the Internet Access Policy is to restrict the usage of
Internet to connected computers, which is probably not what you are looking for.
(As a side-note: You have not entered any MAC addresses for selecting applications
for the rule.)

You are probably searching for the Wireless MAC Filter on page 13.
Follow the instructions, which are to
connect the allowed devices, so their MAC address are displayed on the screen,
then add them to the *Permit* list as described:

> To add a device to the MAC Address Filter List, click the device’s *Add to MAC Filter List* checkbox, then click *Add*.

Once that is done, I believe that only these devices are allowed.
Note that this works only for Wireless, as it is always assumed that
devices connected via Ethernet cable are permitted.

If you have problems making this work, look for firmware update.

Comment: Your side note: yes, I posted clean list.

Wireless devices mac filter works properly.

I wish to block all devices that connect via Ethernet cable (except couple specified), but I can't? Or this router is too simple to do so?

Comment: That was also the situation on my NETGEAR router - devices inside the network are always allowed to connect and are assumed safe. You can however place restrictions on their usage of various Internet services via the Internet Access Policy.